# Is the OVERLAPPED::hEvent set even if pipe connection is immediate with ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED?

Tags: windows, winapi, named-pipes, windows-networking

If, after an asynchronous ConnectNamedPipe(), one gets ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED from GetLastError(), will the event in the OVERLAPPED structure passed to the function still be set, or does it only get set if the result was ERROR_IO_PENDING?

A secondary question is, if the completion notification mode is set to FILE_SKIP_SET_EVENT_ON_HANDLE, documentation specifies that the handle's event won't be set, but that the OVERLAPPED structure's event will still be set, if existing. My question is, what is the use of the handle event, and why is that setting not default?

Answer (score 0):

From [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-server-using-overlapped-i-o)  if `GetLastError()` returned `ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED` then you have to set the event yourself.